# How to handle mongodb relation modeling with webflux?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-webflux, dbref

I have an old-ish (3 years) service I need to maintain and just joined the team. It is a spring-webflux app with mongodb (4). All models are defined with `lombok` and where there are relations between them, `@DBRef` annotation was used. It works fine, but now I have to bump up spring (and the rest of the dependencies) and I just realized `@DBRef` is no longer supported.

Somehow, I understand the decision, but I couldn't find any straight forward alternative other than doing myself all the cascade operations.

So, is there any easier way to approach this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@DBRef` has been replaced by `@DocumentReference` some time ago.

`@DocumentReference`: Applied at the field to indicate it is to be stored as a pointer to another document. This can be a single value (the `id` by default), or a Document provided via a converter.

This very simple example shows how it works:

```java
   public class Account {
     private String id;
     private Float total;
   }
  
   public class Person {
     private String id;
     @DocumentReference
     private List<Account> accounts;
   }
```

For more details, have a look at the official docu:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations

Comment: Indeed, I was exploring the option of having manual references. I was also hoping I missed some bit of documentation where something was added to keep the `automagic` of `@DBRef`. Seems like this is the only option. Thanks for confirming it.